# Python "instance has no attribute ..."

Tags: python, methods, attributes

I have some problem with Python, so heres my class to this point:

```
class Rectangle:

def __init__(self, x1=0, y1=0, x2=0, y2=0):
    if(x1 > x2):
        raise ValueError("x1 cannot be bigger than x2!")
    if(y1 > y2):
        raise ValueError("y1 cannot be bigger than y2!")
    self.pt1 = Point(x1, y1)
    self.pt2 = Point(x2, y2)

def __str__(self):      
    return str("[(" + str(self.pt1.x) + ", " + str(self.pt1.y) + "), (" + str(self.pt2.x) + ", " + str(self.pt2.y) + ")]")

def __repr__(self):        
    return str("Rectangle(" + str(self.pt1.x) + ", " + str(self.pt1.y) + ", " + str(self.pt2.x) + ", "+ str(self.pt2.y) + ")")

def __eq__(self, other): 
    return (self.pt1== other.pt1 and self.pt2 == other.pt2)

def __ne__(self, other):       
    return not self == other

def center(self):         
    return Point((self.pt2.x - self.pt1.x) / 2, (self.pt2.y - self.pt1.y) / 2)
```

and when I try to use method "center" in another class like that:

```
class TestRectangle(unittest.TestCase):

    def setUp(self):
        self.first = Rectangle(1, 2, 3, 4)
        self.second = Rectangle(2, 2, 4, 5)

    def test_init(self):
        with self.assertRaises(ValueError):
            Rectangle(5, 1, 2, 3)
        self.assertEqual(self.first.pt1, Point(1, 2))
        self.assertEqual(self.first.pt2, Point(3, 4))
        self.assertEqual(self.second.pt1.x, 2)      

    def test_str(self):
        self.assertEqual(str(self.first), "[(1, 2), (3, 4)]")

    def test_repr(self):
        self.assertEqual(repr(self.first), "Rectangle(1, 2, 3, 4)")

    def test_eq(self):
        self.assertTrue(self.first == Rectangle(1,2,3,4))
        self.assertFalse(self.first == self.second)

    def test_ne(self):
        self.assertFalse(self.first != Rectangle(1,2,3,4))
        self.assertTrue(self.first != self.second)

    def test_center(self):
        self.assertEqual(self.first.center(), Point(2, 2.5))
```

I got this message:

```
Rectangle instance has no attribute "center".
```

I dunno what to do now, why don't it see my method?

Comment: You should edit your first code segment to include how you defined your class `Rectangle` for completeness.

Comment: Also, `setUp` shouldn't contain any assert* calls.  Consider moving the `assertRaises` to its own test method.

Comment: Ok, fixed, thanks! :)

Comment: You should ensure the methods are properly indented; `center` may be a function defined in the module alongside the class `Rectangle`, instead of a method of that class.

Comment: How can I fix my indents in notepad++?

Comment: Don't fix the indentation in notepad; edit your posting directly on this site.

Comment: Don't edit on NotePad; edit directly on this site.  There's a line of options "share edit close flag" at the bottom of the posting.  Those **def**s in the first code block should all be within the class, but your posting shows them at the same level -- which would cause the problem.

Answer (score 4):

Reading your code, it appears you define `center` outside of the `Rectangle` class, because of an indentation error.

Therefore, `Rectangle` instances do not have any `center` method.

I tried with the right indentation, and it did work.